# Iterate all Rows of the data frame and calculate the sum of a column & stop iteration if column sum = 1 & print row with iterations count

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, iteration, rows

I created a data frame with 15 columns x 32768 rows. In this I calculated the sum of 13th column(Di) and got the sum = 2.1e-06.
[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNiSi.png). Here is the sample of my dataframe

Now I want to iterate through the rows until this sum = 1 and finally print all the values in the row and also the count of iterations.

For example:
for 32,768 rows = 2.1e-06
if let say after 1 million iterations the 13th column reaches 1 then I want to print the row.

I tried this code but this is iterating only until 32,768 rows (i.e, 32,768+32,768). and printing the rows. But I want to know at sum = 1

```
if D_sum[0] < 1: #Sum of 13th column # D_sum = 2.1e-06
count = 0
#repeat the experiment (all columns) from 1 to 32767 until D_sum = 1
for row in df.iterrows():
    count += 1
    D_sum[0] += (df[['Di']].sum()).values
    print(D_sum)
    #print(row)
    if D_sum[0] > 1 : #(Condition)
        print('count', count)
        print(D_sum)
        print(row)
        break
```

Actual output:

```
8.13e-06
1.2e-06.. so on up to 
.
.
0.04 (only 19,041 iterations) #this is iterating only at 32,768 at max and printing D_sum but
```

I need iterations to continue until D_sum = 1 or near to 1.

```
#('prints all rows')

Expected Output:
8.13e-06
1.2e-06.. so on up to 
.
.
1 (#1 million iterations approx)
('print row)
```

Comment: What is your if-block on the first line wrapping? Also I noticed you don't have a case for `D_sum == 1` (only `< 1` and `> 1`). Since you're working with very small numbers, there may be some shenanigans with rounding (e.g. `1 - 1e-17` is rounded to 1)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. 'If' in the first line is a condition I gave to check if D_sum (summation of all values in 13th column Di) is < 1 then iteration of rows is started and continued until if D_sum > 1 then print D_sum, row and iteration count. Yes, since my numbers are very small even its some where near to 1 also ok for me.

Comment: This `if` does nothing because there's neighter something behind the colon, nor anothing indented after it.

Comment: hmm maybe, I have to check it. Could you please improve my code to get desired output.